# How to create a FlexBox layout that wraps and flex items are fluid but equal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Apologies if this is a duplicate question; I did search quite a bit but there are so many FlexBox questions (it's a confusing topic!).  Anyway, I'm trying to create a horizontal row of boxes which have a minimum size and therefore will wrap when there are too many to fit on the one row.  This part I have completed.

The problem is, it doesn't seem possible to *both* have the flex items fluid so that they fill up the parent container *and* have them all stay the same width between rows.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it certainly seems that there probably isn't a way but thought I'd throw it out there in case I missed something.

Comment: And no, I'm not interested in trying Grids just yet.  The browser support isn't quite mature enough.

Comment: how do you figure CSS Grids has better support than Flexbox? The oldest browser that supports it is desktop Chrome 63, which was only released last December. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: So if you have 6 items, 3 go onto the first row with widths: 100, 150, 200. Is your goal to make it so stuff on the second row is 100, 150 and 200 too - even if by being fully "fluid" they'd have a different width?

Comment: @FabioLolli, can you explain more what you mean?  I don't want to set widths since that defeats the purpose of a fluid fexbox layout.

Comment: @TNguyen yeah I was just tying to understand what is your goal with some numbers as an example - does the second row have to reflect the same widths on the first row, block by block?

Comment: @FabioLolli "...and flex items are fluid but equal"